# Problem starting Tor Browser 6, using Windows 7, 64-bit

Tags: help, error, startup

After I start up my computer, I make sure the internet is connected.

Then I try to start torbrowser, last upgrade was to version 6.0.4.

I have problems getting it to start now.  I keep getting a pop up error that says:

> Tor Launcher:
>   Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
>   Connecting to the Tor network failed (no route to host - ###.###.#.###:####)."

I get this every time i start up my computer and I always have to close it down and Exit.  I will try again sometimes 2-4 times to start it before I get a connection, and sometimes it won't connect at all so I'm forced to use a different browser.

I did not *not* have this problem in previous versions, so for now I have gone back to version 5.0.2 and it works fine, I never get that error.

Please tell me if this will be fixed in a near future upgrade.

Thank you very much.

Comment: PS.  Sometimes the error will say "could not connect to Tor control port".

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software or other "security" software installed?

Comment: I did have antivirus but it recently expired, so it's not functional at the moment. (yea, bad, i know)

Comment: I tried updating to 6.0.5 but still have the same problem.  It seems I get the error " "could not connect to Tor control port" most of the time, the previously stated error only showing from time to time.   I have to downgrade back to 5.0.2 again, but the problem with that is some web pages won't load, showing I need to update my browser in order to see them.  So I am stuck.  Please help.  And please let me know if this will be fixed in the next update.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same problem, just did the upgrade for Tor browser and no I am unable to connect at all. Without resetting my whole computer how do I go back to my previous version?

Comment: "no route to host" sounds like a local networking issue, not an issue with the software.

Answer (score 0):

You have a censorship in your case, so let's find it! Please post these data:

- Traceroute and ping(yes/no) to the IP's in your log
- Your `torrc` config
- Your `ipconfig /all` - scrubble your external IP if you have it directly on your PC!
- Traceroute and ping(yes/no) to your bridges - **scrubbling the IP's**!!!

It's safe, because Tor directories IP's are hardcoded to the source and publically available, so no leaks possible. Add the data - and I'll be able to help you more specificly. If you don't want to publish it here - drop a line and we can have a private Skype chat about it

Comment: I don't believe it is a censorship issue based on two things.  First, it has happened on 3 different networks that I connect through.  Second, the problem goes away when I downgrade back to 5.0.2.  The only problem with using 5.0.2 though is that I can't view all the webpages and will sometimes get a message saying "you must update your browser to be able to view this page".

The other thing I noticed is that although I still have the problem with 6.0.5, it is much worse with 6.0.4.

Comment: As for skyping the information you asked about, the downloaded version blocks all tor connections and the web version will not work while I am having this problem, so I can not use skype right now.

Comment: @user14360 it seems to be exactly the site-wide censorship, very looking-like-that, beleive my experience. Have you tried a standalone Tor instance with `-f /path/to/your/config/file` ? Do you need help with the config?